# bochs error "could not open rom image file"

Tags: centos7, bochs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lE0tJ.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eozfc.png)

it just show me that could not open the rom image , and I thought it was the security , and I chmod 777 to the file ,  but it does not work . Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I also changed the address form 0xf0000 to 0xe0000, it does not work too. what should i do ? Any help will be greatly apperciated.

Comment: if you think that was the security, use `ls -Z` to check the selinux file context. let's me know the result.

Comment: okhaha ,I was confused ,it shows : rwx-rwx-rwx mycentos myceotos unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 BGABIOS-lgpl-latest

Comment: I think  I  have fixed the problem, I found the sample file  bochsrc.sample_file and  I changed the path , now it works .  Thank you yaha.